# How to make a Sails model point to distinct databases on the go?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm creating a Sails application for which I got to do a panel administration for transactions to a model database. The point is, the backend architecture and data administration requires distinct databases for for same model in Sails application.

So, my model looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

  connection: 'seasonDB',
  autoPK: false,

  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'string',
      primaryKey: true,
      required: true
    },
    avatar: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    price: {
      type: 'integer',
      defaultsTo: function () {
        var prices = [ 7000000, 5000000, 4000000, 2500000, 1000000 ];
        return prices[_.random(prices.length -1)];
      }
    },
    description: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    status: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['suspended', 'inSquad','injured','out']
    }
  }
};
```

Where `'seasonDB'` is defined at `config/connections.js`:

```
  seasonDB: {
    adapter: process.env.SEASON_DB_ADAPTER,
    host: process.env.SEASON_DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.SEASON_DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.SEASON_DB_USER,
    password: process.env.SEASON_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.SEASON_DB_DB
  }
```

So, is there any way to change the environmental variables and somehow reload the models with out reloading whole application?

Answer (score 3):

There is a hook for sails.js named sails-hook-autoreload. It tracks changes into controllers, models and apply changes without manual reload. You could try to use it or create something similar only for models.

Comment: But that will reload whole application, leasing any ongoing HTTP request, right?

Comment: Actually it wouldn't reload an application. It will reinitiate orm hook and rebind routes. So only this hook will be reloaded. But my suggestion is to remove functionality related to routing from hook.

Comment: So you mean like: *use the hook which will reload ORM and configure it to keep routes ontouched*

Comment: Yep. You could just copy this hook and remove controllers and services watchers.

Comment: Sure. If you will have problems ping me in twitter